# Relocate legend entries and axis labels in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Hey there I'm new to R and have a very small question

I have the following dataset:

```
head(risk_free_rate_comparison)

   Dates `       Swap rate` `Sovereign bond yield rate` `Swap rate - Sovereign bond yield rate`
  <dttm>         <dbl>       <dbl>                       <dbl>
1 2007-01-02     408.9       380.9568                    27.9432
2 2007-01-03     410.3       380.4535                    29.8465
3 2007-01-04     409.2       381.3993                    27.8007
4 2007-01-05     414.3       385.0663                    29.2337
5 2007-01-08     413.1       384.2545                    28.8455
6 2007-01-09     415.5       384.9770                    30.5230
```

,with the following plot:

```
ggplot(d, aes(Dates, value, color = variable, linetype = variable)) +
+     geom_line() +
+     labs(color = NULL, linetype = NULL) +
+     theme_classic() +
+     theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
+     ylab("Rates in bp")
```

[image: riskfreeratecomparison]

I'm satisfied with the position of the legend, but it is it possible to have the entries one below the other instead of side by side?

Furthermore I would like to move the axis labels a little bit away from the axis for aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My theme() addition at the end will address both of your problems:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(am = factor(am, labels = c("auto", "manu"))) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(wt, mpg, color = am, linetype = am)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(color = NULL, linetype = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  ylab("Rates in bp") + 
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.direction = "vertical",
    legend.box.margin = margin(t = 30),
    axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20))
  )
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly! However I was a little unspecific. I would like to move only the x-axis labels, "Rates in bp" and "Dates" outside, and not the numbers on the axis.

Comment: @rbonac, see my updates to the answer above. You can also find a lot of these nuanced adjustments by typing ?theme into your console.

Comment: Yes I saw and used it, most of it worked, but if I put in for example:
axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20)
the y-axis label does not move to the left, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For  "axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20)", t is the top margin, b would be the bottom margin, and l and r would be left and right margins. If you want to move the y-axis title to the left you need to increase its margin on the right using "axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 20)". The numbers are font size. Default margins are the same font size as your text.